# Get X509 Certificate from mage signed manifest file

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate, mage

I have an `OutlookAddin.vsto` file (yes, its an Outlook addin VSTO file) which contains a signed certificate, signed using [mage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx). It successfully created a `<X509Certificate>` tags which contain the encoded public certificate as far as I can tell embedded within it, of this format:

> MIIFBDCCA+ygAwIBAgIQeCmDjQ...3OsgfHUZkAl/GR77wxDooVNr2Hk+aohlDpG9J+PxeQiAohItHIG4=

How can I read this certificate back as an X509 certificate in C#? I can't seem to find a suitable X509Certificate2 [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) to make this magic happen in my C#, .NET application.

Comment: This string probably represents the certificate raw data encoded as base64. Use `Convert.FromBase64String` method to convert this into a `byte[]` and then use the `X509Certificate2` constructor that takes a `byte[]`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad It worked, thank you. Please post this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string probably represents the certificate raw data encoded as base64.
Use the [Convert.FromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert this into a `byte[]` and then use the [X509Certificate2 constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `byte[]` to create the certificate object.